# Can't POST MultiPartEntity in Android application

Tags: android, apache, post, httpclient, multipartform-data

I am trying to send an image using MultiPartEntity and HttpClient in Android, but keep getting the exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()`

Here is my code:

```
public boolean enrollImage(String id, byte[] image) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://example.com/"+id+"/images/");
    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("user"+":"+"password").getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("image", new ByteArrayBody(image, "image/jpg", "image.jpg"));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've added the newer Apache libraries `httpmime-4.2.5.jar`, `httpclient-4.2.5.jar`, `httpcore-4.2.4.jar`, and `apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar` to my project.

How can I get this this running so that I can POST

Comment: http://goo.gl/9qKma  you should check that example against your multipart code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was just confusing the request entity that I was sending with the response entity that I wanted to parse as json. Line 12 of that code should be

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
```

NOT

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Problem fixed. Guess it's time for me to buy a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Everyone needs a rubber duck!

Comment: @QRohlf thank you for linking that wikipedia article I never read about that.